# What is Doppler Spread

Tags: wireless, basic

What is the plain English explanation of the Doppler Spread?

Looking at different sources I come across complicated definitions which I struggle to understand.

Example for such one:

> Doppler spread is a measure of the *spectral broadening* caused by
>   the time rate of change of the mobile radio channel, and is defined as the range of
>   frequencies over which the received Doppler spectrum is essentially non-zero.

What does the spectral broadening mean?

[the reference link](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/14911/en/)

useful link: http://www.einstein-online.info/spotlights/doppler

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, and by reading http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr03/fading/doppler.htm I think the following is the answer.

1) Imagine you transmit a short burst of a sine wave of a fixed frequency.

2) When there is no relative motion between the transmitter and the receiver, due to multipath the receiver can receive the same signal at different times, because a one copy took a short path and arrived quickly, another took a long path (header in a different dircection, bounced off a building, and reflected back toward the receiver).  This is multipath.

3) Now add relative motion to the scenario above. Because of the different incident angle, not only will the longer path signal arrive later, but it will have a arrive with a different incident angle, and therefore (due to the Doppler Effect) it will have a different frequency.  So the Doppler spread would be the difference of the two frequencies received (even though there is only a single fixed frequency being transmitted).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a signal of a given frequency is transmitted in a medium with moving reflectors. The received signal has slight frequency variations from the original signal due to the interaction with those moving objects. This is what I believe spectral broadening means. This frequency variation at a given time is called spectral shift. The standard deviation of multiple spectral shifts is the Doppler spread.

> Signals traveling along different paths can have different Doppler shifts, corresponding to different rates of change in phase. The difference in Doppler shifts between different signal components contributing to a single fading channel tap is known as the Doppler spread. Channels with a large Doppler spread have signal components that are each changing independently in phase over time.

See this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading) page and this [EDA Board](http://www.edaboard.com/thread269716.html) thread.

Answer (score 1):

Doppler spread is the range of frequencies over which the received Doppler spectrum is essentially non zero.

When a pure sinusoidal of frequency  is transmitted, the received signal spectrum, called the Doppler spectrum, will have components in the range + to −, where  is the Doppler shift.

depends on speed and the angle of signal arrival.

= / x (cos), where  is the the angle between the direction of motion and the direction of signal arrival: therefore, positive  when moving toward the source, negative when moving away from the signal source
Note that the maximum Doppler shift is  = /.

Coherence time quantifies the similarity of the channel response at different times. In other words, the time duration over which two received signals have strong potential for amplitude correlation.

Coherence time is the time domain dual of Doppler spread, and approximated as c =9/(16), where  is the maximum Doppler shift.

Coherence time implies that two signals arriving with time difference greater than c are affected differently by the channel.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an analogy with sound waves, it's easier to understand. For example, if you are standing on a street, and an ambulance passes with the sirens on, you'll notice the pitch rises as it comes near you and lowers when it draws appart. This happens because the source of the sound waves is moving, so the waves get to you "distorted". Broader waves means lower frequency, thus making the pitch lower.  The same principle applies to electromagnetic waves.

Comment: I think you gave me a broad definition of what the `Doppler Effect` is, or am I mistaken? Doppler Spread seems as something different, based on what I have read so far.

Comment: As far as I understand, the broadening of the spectrum named Doppler Spread, is based on the Doppler Effect itself. When the source of the signal is moving, the signal suffers from Doppler Spread, caused by the same principles as the Doppler Effect.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia has a clear description of doppler spread on the "Fading" site.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading)  Whether that nice, clear description is correct is a different question...

To sum up wikipedia, doppler spread is the result of the doppler effect on all the various channels in use at one time.